# How can I dynamically loading external configuration settings in a React JS app?

Tags: reactjs, configuration, webpack

I'm currently using Webpack to manage configuration for my React JS app.

I have a `config.development.json` file that is loaded by my development build script. It contains

```
{
  "primary1Color": "pink"
}
```

It's loaded in the Webpack script as follows

```
externals: {
    configuration: JSON.stringify(require("./config.development.json"))
}
```

There's a similar set up for production builds.

I reference the config parameters in my app as follows

```
import configuration from "configuration";

const mainColor = configuration.primary1Color;
```

This is all working.

However, I'd like to allow the settings to be configured *post-deployment*---i.e. have the app read the config file when it runs. Then, if customers wish to change the color scheme, they can do so without me having to rebuild the app.

How can I get the app to dynamically load my JSON config file?

Comment: A core question is how often will they update these values. Having to do a new deployment for changing a color is silly. However, if you're only doing this every year, then loading data from a database or API is also silly.
Allowing people to edit JSON files is also, not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to bundle it with webpack. You can use normal ajax call to load the json or use **script.js**.

https://github.com/ded/script.js

However if you really want to use webpack loader, you can try **external-loader**.

https://github.com/sheerun/external-loader

More discussion here:
["Require external (unmanaged) file"](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach would be to create an API endpoint that react interacts with to load them.

Comment: but how will you make sure this config is loaded before react app loads